# Python 3.5 How I can get rid of the eval in my Class function

Tags: python, class, eval, init, self

I have a Class named NumApprox, it takes a string as input (a Mathematical expression containing a variable 'x') and all the methods in it are just different approachs to integrate the math expression given a numerical value for 'x'

expected input examples:

```
  input = " x ** 2 * log( x ) "

  input = "1 / sqrt(2*pi) * exp(- x **2 / 2) "
```

I was wondering how can I isolate and take control of the 'x' variable provided by the string input and use it from anywhere within my class without the 'eval' function.

This is what I've done, but I don't like that 'eval' function and given my limited knowledge of Python Classes ... I'ld like to know if there's a better alternative to the 'eval' ?

```
from math import pi, sqrt, exp, log

class NumApprox:

    def __init__(self, expr):
        self.expr = expr

    def pdf(self, x):
        self.x = x 
        self.ev = eval( self.expr.replace('x', 'self.x') )
        return self.ev

    def integrate_rect_method(self, A, B, n): 
        ...
```

Comment: If you want to evaluate arbitrary expressions without resorting to `eval`, you're probably going to have to start looking into a parser of some sort.

Comment: better use modules like [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/)

Comment: As an aside, what do you think `self.expr.replace('x', 'self.x')` will do when `expr` is `exp(x)` ?

Comment: It will return a _NameError : name 'x' is not defined_ unless you meant `"exp( x )"` in which case, it will return `" exp( self.x ) "`. expr needs to be string; it's the only way I know of to make calls to the same class object for integrating arbitrary expressions.

Comment: @jwdasdk No it won't return `exp(self.x)` ... it will return `eself.xp(self.x)`.

Comment: @donkopotamus Yup ! That's true. A little leading and trailing space around the 'x'  is needed (ie. `self.expr.replace(' x ', 'self.x')` ) and same goes for the 'x' in expr,  `expr = ' exp( x ) '` for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use module [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/)

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

x, y, z = symbols("x y z")

input = " x ** 2 * log( x ) "

#expr = sympify(input) # `sympify` uses `eval`
expr = parse_expr(input)

print(expr)
print(expr.subs({x:2}))

input = "1 / sqrt(2*pi) * exp(- x **2 / 2) "

#expr = sympify(input) # `sympify` uses `eval`
expr = parse_expr(input)

print(expr)
print(expr.subs({x:2}))
```

result:

```
x**2*log(x)
4*log(2)

sqrt(2)*exp(-x**2/2)/(2*sqrt(pi))
sqrt(2)*exp(-2)/(2*sqrt(pi))
```

[Parsing](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html)

[Basic Operations](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html) and 
[Sympify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#converting-strings-to-sympy-expressions)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and demo, will give it a try and test. One quick question though, does the SymPy module heavily rely on evals to handle arbitrary expressions ?

Comment: I found only information that `sympify` uses `eval`. If you need more information you will have to check source code - there are links to code on SymPy page. If you don't want `eval` then you will have to build parser - you can use [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) - but it need more work.